# Could not find xml file

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I'm studing wcf. In my test project Service read data from xml file and then send it to client. Data is array of type "myClass".
Service class has a function
 Collapse | Copy Code

```
    private XDocument GetDB()
    {

        string filePath = "SampleDB.xml"           
        return XDocument.Load(filePath);
    }
```

This function works when I run the service application. But when I call service from client it doesn't work.

The copy of xml file located in **bin->debug** folder. but when i run programm, I see exception like this

> Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\Common7\IDE\SampleDB.xml'.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, give the full path to your file, should end with bin\debug\SampleDB.xml

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the xml file using `Server.MapPath`.

```
string filePath = Server.MapPath("SampleDB.xml");
```

That's the solution of "Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\SampleDB.xml'.